# GridSearchCV output problems in Scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, hyperparameters

I'd like to perform a hyperparameter search for selecting preprocessing steps and models in sklearn as follows:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([("combiner", PolynomialFeatures()),
                     ("dimred", PCA()),
                     ("classifier", RandomForestClassifier())])

parameters = [{"combiner": [None]},
              {"combiner": [PolynomialFeatures()], "combiner__degree": [2], "combiner__interaction_only": [False, True]},

              {"dimred": [None]},
              {"dimred": [PCA()], "dimred__n_components": [.95, .75]},

              {"classifier": [RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, class_weight="balanced")],
               "classifier__max_depth": [5, 10, None]},
              {"classifier": [KNeighborsClassifier(weights="distance")],
               "classifier__n_neighbors": [3, 7, 11]}]

CV = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, cv=5, scoring="f1_weighted", refit=True, n_jobs=-1)
CV.fit(train_X, train_y)
```

Of course, I need the results with the best pipeline with the best parameters. However, when I request best estimators with `CV.best_estimator_` I get only the winning components, not the hyperparameters:

```
Pipeline(steps=[('combiner', None), ('dimred', PCA()),
                ('classifier', RandomForestClassifier())])
```

When I print out the `CV.best_params_`, I get an even shorter info (only with the first element of the `Pipeline`, the `combiner`, no info about `dimred`, `classifier` whatsoever):

```
{'combiner': None}
```

How could I get the best pipeline combination with components and their hyperparameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pipeline` objects have a [`get_params()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.get_params) method which returns the parameters of the pipeline. This includes the parameters of the individual steps as well. Based on your example, the command

```
CV.best_estimator_.get_params()
```

will retrieve all pipeline parameters of the best estimator, including those you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `param_grid` is a list of dictionaries, each such dictionary gives a separate grid, and the search takes place over the disjoint union of those grids.  So the `best_estimator_` and `best_params_` in your case correspond to the single-point grid with `combiner=None` and everything else as defined in the original `pipeline`.  (And the search has never explored `combiner=None` with other hyperparameters.)