# How to retrain pipeline with different data in Scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

I do a machine learning model training with pipelines, K-fold cross validation with Python and sklearn on a subset of my all historical data (omitting a test set), along the following:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([("combiner", PolynomialFeatures()),
                     ("dimred", PCA()),
                     ("classifier", RandomForestClassifier())])

parameters = [...]

CV = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, cv=5, scoring="f1_weighted", refit=True, n_jobs=-1)
CV.fit(train_X, train_y)
```

So far, so good. However, at the end, I want to retrain the winning pipeline hyperparameter combination on my full X and y, without any cross validation. How could I have this? Simply applying `CV.fit(X, y)` again would re-doing the whole alternating process with CV, which is obviously unnecessary. I could also parse `CV.get_params()` for the best combination hyperparameters and build up the pipeline again accordingly, but this somehow seems clumsy and unprofessional...

Comment: how about saving your CV and loading it for later use?

Comment: This wouldn't change estimator's weights (or, in this case: decisions) in the pipeline, but would simply apply the pipeline. What I want is to apply the pipeline with the specific components and hyperparameters of these (so have them unchanged) based on the CV's winning formula, and do recalculate estimator's weights/decision logic in the pipeline based on the new, larger/fuller full data without, of course, any CV or further evaluation). Right now I can do it only by hand (inspecting CV's report and redefining a new pipeline with the best settings).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is in the [GridSearchCV documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html). See the Attributes section: `best_estimator_` is where the best model is stored, so you can access it from there after you are done with fitting. You can use it by directly calling `CV.best_estimatory_', you can make a new reference to it or pickle it for later using [joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.dump.html), ie.:

```
import joblib
joblib.dump(CV.best_estimator_, 'my_pipeline.pkl')
```

Later you can load your model for further work:

```
import joblib
my_pipeline = joblib.load('my_pipeline.pkl')
```

If you do not need the model, but only its hyperparameters you can access those from the `best_params_` attribute, ie.:

```
CV.best_params_
```

which is a dictionary the best settings that you can use to construct a new pipeline.

Comment: `best_estimator_` is the result of the actual training process. I do not want to use this pipeline #1, but train another pipeline #2 on another data WITH the elements and hyperparameters of the pipeline #1.

Comment: Then use `best_params_` like I mentioned after the edit. You should read the docs to see what else you can get from the CV results.

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted to do, but having a specific pipeline with alternatives, best_params_ somehow doesn't work, doesn't give back full parameter dict. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63212770/gridsearchcv-output-problems-in-scikit-learn

Comment: What about `CV.best_estimator_.get_params()` like the accepted answer suggested?